# Assembly problem when using a .ashx file in my layouts folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a *.ashx file in my "Layouts" folder for sharepoint and it doesnt seem like I can access any of my custom made classes outside of the Layouts folder.  Is there a problem with the assembly?  I keep getting the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'PropertiesHelper' does not exist in the namespace 'Company.SharePoint.Test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have tried to put a using statement to import the class but it seems like it isnt able to find it.  I also tried writing out the full path of the function like: `Company.SharePoint.Test.PropertiesHelper.someMethod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when this happens to me, it's because I forgot to actually deploy the assembly to the GAC (or locally depending on how you're doing it). Either way, it can't find the assembly because it's not in the right location or not trusted.